# Raspberry Pi Headless start question

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, debian

Can I remove the 2 headless start files which are located in `/boot`? Specifically, can I remove `ssh` and `wpa_supplicant.conf` after I've finished the first boot and reconfigured everything with `raspi-config`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about Raspbian. At the first boot from a newly prepared SD card, if an ssh file and a wpa_supplicant.conf file are found in /boot then they are both moved. You would not be able to delete them, as they would be gone already. If this does not happen, something is wrong.